# Open a new activity with a button from a static fragment?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments

I have an Activity (main) with four fragments. I want to add one button to the third fragment that opens another Activity (secondary) with three fragments. When I press back I want to return to the main Activity.

I have searched for an answer, but I can't find one that works. My fragments' codes are inside the main activity, and the fragments are static because otherwise the app Force Closes when rotating to landscape mode.

I took the button code from here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

```
public class fragmentFour extends Fragment  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), musikteori_ackord.class);
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout1, container, false);
        }
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAckord);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }
```

Errors:

```
 - Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'
 - Cannot resolve symbol 'v'
```

Comment: How can someone "open" a class? Just wondering...

Comment: Sorry, Im new to Android programming.

Comment: It's is referred to as "Activity" not class

Comment: An `Activity` is a class and saying they want to open it isn't a big deal...let's be productive. Anyway, @johngru show us the code you are trying and post the logcat if it is crashing. Also, you may want to accept answers that help you...its proper etiquette.

Comment: @codeMagic I will put the code up soon. What do you mean by "accept answers"? :)

Comment: Of course I'll do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just add a `Button` in the third fragment and `onClick` of that button, start an `Intent` that opens up the new desired `Activity` containing the other three fragments.

[EDIT]

Try this:

```
public class fragmentFour extends Fragment  {

      Intent intent;
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout1, container, false);
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), musikteori_ackord.class);
        final Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.buttonAckord);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return root;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me error: Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'

Comment: @johgru Oops my bad! It should be `return root;` Edited the answer as well.